# Meteor connection lost randomly ,mongo collection find return null

Tags: mongodb, vue.js, meteor

Meteor connection lost randomly ,mongo collection find return null

```js
Data.find({}, {sort: {createdAt: 1}});
```

safari open web page ,get the current data first ，and wait for few minutes and collection data will refresh, seems that meteor websocket was disconnect or something happened， the find function by mongo can not get data anymore,my  tag info on web page will display none data

randomly appear，what should I do that can find the real problem？

Comment: or how can I observe the meteor websocket work status?

Comment: the websocket is work well .I find the problem is subscribe function in client is called many times by different pages.Maybe when the current page is show ,but the surscribe unsub by other page when destoryed. I am trying to resolve

Answer (score 1):

> what should I do that can find the real problem

You can write a `Tracker.autorun` routine that automatically refreshes when a reactive datasources "changes". You can then observe the change, for example by logging it to the console.

To get the connection status you have to use `Meteor.status()`, which is by fact a reactive data source.

Both together allow you to get informed, when the connection changes:

*client/main.js*

```js
Meteor.startup(() => {
  Tracker.autorun(() => {
    const connection = Meteor.status() // triggers observer when change
    console.log(connection.connected) // true / false
    console.log(connection.status) // one of [connected, connecting, failed, waiting, offline]
    console.log(reason)
  })
})
```

Readings:

https://docs.meteor.com/api/connections.html#Meteor-status

https://docs.meteor.com/api/tracker.html#Tracker-autorun

Since you tagged `vue`:

https://guide.meteor.com/vue.html#vue-and-meteor-realtime-data-layer

Comment: thanks ,I try and find the websocket is ok,maybe other reason cause this problem.

Comment: I was use the sub-cache for meteor,I remove the package and the data run good,so I think the sub-cache package cause this problem

Comment: Do you mean `ccorcos:subs-cache`? Could you please open an issue on their GitHub and create a minimal repo for reproduction? I will take a deeper look at it.

Comment: @GuoRoy did this answer solved your problem then please mark it as accepted, so others with similar problems have an orientation